# What happens if I repeat a CSS style in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-5

In jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css, I found this gem:

```
/* IE6 IFRAME FIX (taken from datepicker 1.5.3 */
.ui-datepicker-cover {
    display: none; /*sorry for IE5*/
    display/**/: block; /*sorry for IE5*/
    position: absolute; /*must have*/
    ...
}
```

Apparently, repeating the `display` style is a workaround for a bug in IE. If I understand CSS correctly, this should behave like `display: block;` (i.e. the first entry *should* be overridden by the second).

For which version(s) of IE is this necessary? Only 5.x or 6 as well?

Comment: Your understanding is correct, I just can't recall which specific version of IE trips up on this CSS. The hack lies in the `/**/`.

Comment: Rather odd they even bothered with those considering jQuery *core's* support starts with IE6...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: http://www.communis.co.uk/dithered/css_filters/css_only/property_empty_comment.html:

```
#testElement {
   color/**/: #00cc00;
   }
```

> **Applied By**
>   ..
>   Win IE 5.5 - 6.x
>   ..
>
> **Not Applied By**
>   Win IE 4.0 - 5.0
>   ..

So, the comment `/*sorry for IE5*/` aptly describes the hack - the *zero IE5.0 users* still in existence will not be able to see any `.ui-datepicker-cover` elements.

Comment: Nice digging. That's some seriously old-skool filtering. I don't think I ever used this particular one, even back then.